# How to set date time format for Datatables used in whole winform application?

Tags: c#, winforms, datatables, cultureinfo

I am working on an application in which I have set default culture for whole application.

```
static void Main()
{
    try
    {
        #region set date pattern for whole application
        try
        {
            CultureInfo culture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
            culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ShortDateFormat"];
            culture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LongDateFormat"];

            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            RCOP.SmartClient.General.SaveLog(ex);
        }
        #endregion
    }
    ....
}
```

The date time format is not applying on `datatables` and date column in `datatables` has date format as set in computer which results in exception if user change computer `datetime` format. so I have to use following code for individual `datatables`

```
dataTable.Locale.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
dataTable.Locale.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern;
```

The issue is that I have to apply above setting in whole application (more then 200 places as win app is very large) where I have used `datatables`.

How to apply `datetime` setting in one place so that all `datatables` have the same `datetime` format as set in default culture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have your custom `DataTable` with your custom `culture` always set to `ShortDatePattern`, because your `DataTable` format is just use for displaying, dates and `Locale` is not `static` it can't be inherited or overridden globally in application, each `DataTable` has it's own `DateTimeFormat`.
So do something like:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyDataTable : DataTable
{
    void SetCulture()
    {
        this.Locale.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
        this.Locale.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern;
    }
    public MyDataTable()
        : base()
    {
        SetCulture();
    }

    public MyDataTable(string tableName)
        : base(tableName)
    {
        SetCulture();
    }

    public MyDataTable(string tableName, string tableNamespace)
        : base(tableName, tableNamespace)
    {
        SetCulture();
    } 

    /// <summary>
    /// Needs using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    /// </summary>
    public MyDataTable(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context)
    {
        SetCulture();
    } 
}
```

and replace all `DataTable` with `MyDataTable` in whole the application.
Or do this:

```
public interface ISource
{
    DataTable Table { get; }
} 
public class MySource : ISource
{
    private DataTable table;
    public DataTable Table
    {
        get
        {
            if (table == null)
            {
                table = new System.Data.DataTable();
                table.Locale.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
                table.Locale.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern;
            }
            return table;
        }
        private set
        {
            this.table = value;
        }
    } 
}
```

but the first example is better.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways on how you can declare a data table that can be used in your entire application. You can use Singleton, by creating a static class with DataTable property and access it anywhere in your appplication. Another is you can use Dependency Injection, by injecting the instance of a class that contains the DataTable property to your class constructor. [See Dry Principles explained](https://web-techno.net/dry-principle-explained/)